# How to restrict application to devices (UDID) in Apple Enterprise Account?

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I'm developing an application for a company. Because of confidentiality reasons they do not want to publish the app to the app-store. But they also want Device ID's management means if someone left their company but still can use the application or can have application.

I have read the documentation of Enterprise Account. In-House Distribution and Ad-Hoc Distribution.

Need some solid reasons to tell the client about the application confidentiality. Because we cannot manage UDID's runtime. Also tell me the lifeline of Ad-Hoc and In-House builds

We will use secure (Auth) Page to download the application. And application have its own authentication process too.

Thanks

Comment: make webservice to check users UDID each time,..if not matches disallow access.and obiously you can manage UDID database at server runtime. I think this once we make ad-hoc disstributionn then we dont have a way to update distribution list untill we make another ipa and distribute

Comment: @preetam you means login/pin etc?

Comment: @preetam you know we cannot access the UDID in iOS5+ so. How to send it to server via web services.

Comment: you are going to make a ad-hoc distribution means you have UDIDs

Comment: @preetam what is the lifeline or AdHoc Distribution? and if I go with In-House then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36380/discussion-between-preetam-and-amir-idev)